# Install and use Az inside PowerShell called from C#

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, .net-6.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to call a PowerShell script that installs and uses `Az` library from C# .NET 6 but I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to run test  because 
New-AzResourceGroup: 
Line |
   8 |      New-AzResourceGroup -Name 'TestRg123' -Location 'eastus2euap'
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'New-AzResourceGroup' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I think it's failing to install `Az` or consider how fast the csharp code finishes, its just ignores the import and install commands.

Note that the actual script I am trying to does a lot more than just creating a resource group so I cannot simplify convert it to use Azure C# SDK.

App.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

var initialState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
initialState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;

using var ps = PowerShell.Create(initialState);
var results = ps.AddScript(@"
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force

# Import Azure module
Import-Module 'Az'
Import-Module 'Az.Accounts'
Import-Module 'Az.RecoveryServices'

try {
    New-AzResourceGroup -Name 'TestRg123' -Location 'eastus2euap'
}
catch
{
    $string_err = $_ | Out-String
    Write-Output ""Failed to run test $testname because $string_err""
}
").Invoke();

foreach (var outputItem in results)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(outputItem);
}
```

ConsoleApp.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.2.6" />
      <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.6" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**UPDATE**

This is what `ps.ErrorBuffer` is showing

[image]

Comment: My first guess would be the target CPU architecture of your C# project - on my system, `New-AzResourceGroup` is visible from the default 'x64' PowerShell prompt, but not the 'x86' version.  If you are using 'x86' or 'AnyCPU', try 'x64' and see if that helps.

Comment: @boxdog No success.

Comment: Set the execution policy to unrestricted. `initialState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted`.  You'll also need to run `Connect-AzAccount` before you can use the Az commandlets

Comment: @Daniel no success. I am getting the same error

Comment: Are you getting other errors before that regarding the install or import modules?  In debug check error streams under ps object

Comment: @Daniel I added a screenshot and update. `ps.ErrorBuffer` was very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Try using the command `Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force` to install the module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Az inside PowerShell Core called from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74007416/install-az-inside-powershell-core-called-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, is the package provider installed? I.e., is it listed under [`Get-PackageProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/get-packageprovider?view=powershell-7.2), or is the PSGallery listed under `Get-PSRepository`? At the bottom of the linked page there's a note that reads

> Important
>
> As of April 2020, the PowerShell Gallery no longer supports Transport
> Layer Security (TLS) versions 1.0 and 1.1. If you are not using TLS
> 1.2 or higher, you will receive an error when trying to access the PowerShell Gallery. Use the following command to ensure you are using
> TLS 1.2:
>
> `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`
>
> For more information, see the announcement in the PowerShell blog.

With that said, your first step should be ensuring the use of *TLS 1.2* by running `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` then trying again. If that doesn't work (*or if not already installed*), re-registering the PSGallery repository would be the next step to take.

```
Unregister-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' # ensures no collision
Register-PSRepository -Default # registers PSGallery when specifying the switch.
```

Comment: No success, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

While it takes longer initially, I would suggest using built in C# tools to call powershell. One note, you must install the powershell modules on each computer that runs the code. That could cause issues. But, you can use something like:

```
        public Collection<PSObject> runAzureCommands(Command _command, string _commandName)
        {
            InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(this.emailLogin, this.emailPass);
            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveID"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
            connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyerrors) => true;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)(0x30 | 0xc0 | 0x300 | 0xc00);
            connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 10;
            Command connectCommand = new Command("Connect-AzureAD");
            connectCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Credential", credential));

            try
            {
                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                    pipe.Commands.Add(connectCommand);
                    var results = pipe.Invoke();
                    var error = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                    if (error.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (PSObject err in error)
                        {
                            //Log the error as needed.
                        }
                    }
                    pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                    pipe.Commands.Add(_command);
                    var results2 = pipe.Invoke();
                    var error2 = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                    if (error2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (PSObject er in error2)
                        {
                            //log the error as needed.
                        }
                    }
                    return results2;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log the exception as needed.
            }
        }
```

This lets you log errors better, and log exceptions better. it also lets you return a PS object if you need to use the created item / output.

To use a function:

```
        public void addAzureGroupMember(object _group, object _user)
        {
            Command command = new Command("Add-AzureADGroupMember");
            command.Parameters.Add("ObjectId", _group);
            command.Parameters.Add("RefObjectId", _user);
            Collection<PSObject> results = runAzureCommands(command, "addAxureGroupMember");
        }
```

Once you build the main function, it lets you create extra functions quickly. Also, when / if it breaks, you only have to change one main function, instead of fixing every single powershell script you created using the template.