# Install Az inside PowerShell Core called from C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to call a PowerShell script that installs and uses `Az` library from C# .NET 6 but I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to run test  because 
New-AzResourceGroup: 
Line |
   8 |      New-AzResourceGroup -Name 'TestRg123' -Location 'eastus2euap'
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'New-AzResourceGroup' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Looking closer at the `ps.ErrorBuffer` show PowerShellCore is having trouble installing Azure module. Apparently [this is not a new problem](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/477)

Program.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

var initialState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
initialState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;

using var ps = PowerShell.Create(initialState);
var results = ps.AddScript(@"
Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget -Scope CurrentUser –Force

Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet -Scope CurrentUser –Force

Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force

# Import Azure module
Import-Module 'Az'
Import-Module 'Az.Accounts'
Import-Module 'Az.RecoveryServices'

try {
    New-AzResourceGroup -Name 'TestRg123' -Location 'eastus2euap'
}
catch
{
    $string_err = $_ | Out-String
    Write-Output ""Failed to run test $testname because $string_err""
}
").Invoke();

foreach (var outputItem in results)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(outputItem);
}
```

ConsoleApp.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.2.6" />
      <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.6" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception - Message:'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType' threw an exception.' Name:'TypeInitializationException' Stack Trace:'   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType.Create(Type tInterface, OrderedDictionary`2 instanceMethods, List`2 delegateMethods, List`1 stubMethods, List`2 usedInstances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.CreateProxy(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast[TInterface](Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterfaceExtensions.As[TInterface](Object instance)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.get_PackageManagementHost()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.SelectProviders(String[] names)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.<get_CachedSelectedProviders>b__23_0()
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.DictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`1 valueFunction)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.Singleton`1.GetOrAdd(Func`1 newInstance, Object primaryKey, Object[] keys)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.SingletonExtensions.GetOrAdd[TResult](Object primaryKey, Func`1 newInstance, Object[] keys)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_CachedSelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.GenerateDynamicParameters()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.AsyncCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.<AsyncRun>b__0()'
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue with `Get-PackageManagement` not loading and it turned out this was because when loading Powershell from C# the $env:PSModulePath is different than what PowerShell is loading from console so PackageManangement module could not be loaded.  PackageManagement was located in `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules\PackageManagement` which isn't a path loaded in when running from C#.  I moved PackageManagement module folder to `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules` folder and this resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Another solution would probably be to update $env:PSModulePath in your script with the correct location to PackageManagement module folder before running `Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force`.  The 2 lines to install Nuget provider and PowerShellGet are probably unnecessary.

Comment: @Daniel not sure how to do that. I have been struggling with this error for some time.

Comment: First, from a powershell console check the install path for `(Get-Module PackageManagement).Path`.  Then at the beginning of your script add this path to the PSModulePath variable with this line `$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";path\of\path\to\module \folder\containing\PackageManagement"` (ex. C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules)

Comment: Found similar issue : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10867,  Try adding the TLS version to you script : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/main/reference/7.2/PackageManagement/Get-PackageProvider.md#notes  Error seems to occur when connecting to Proxy.  TLS version needs to be either TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.

Comment: @jdweng No success unfotuantely. Getting the same error

Comment: It still may be a proxy issue, just not TLS.  See simResources on following : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/mobilenetwork-provision-proxy-sims/?force_isolation=true

Comment: @Node.JS Did you tried changing 'PSModulePath' environment variable values order as mentioned in the link https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/477 by SaladPickles... that workaround seems to be working with PS 7.2.x version

Comment: @Gandhi no success. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Do you have an example that works? this code is intended to run in a Linux pipeline so there is no `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Modules`

Comment: @Node.JS Hi, the change mentioned there is all about changing the environment variables value added in system environment variables in windows... i dont think its a code change... you may have to check the comments there... it says that code change helped him to figure out the issue which is changing the env variables order

Answer (score 1):

While it takes longer initially, I would suggest using built in C# tools to call powershell. One note, you must install the powershell modules on each computer that runs the code. That could cause issues. But, you can use something like:

```
    public Collection<PSObject> runAzureCommands(Command _command, string _commandName)
    {
        InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(this.emailLogin, this.emailPass);
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveID"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyerrors) => true;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)(0x30 | 0xc0 | 0x300 | 0xc00);
        connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 10;
        Command connectCommand = new Command("Connect-AzureAD");
        connectCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Credential", credential));

        try
        {
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipe.Commands.Add(connectCommand);
                var results = pipe.Invoke();
                var error = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                if (error.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (PSObject err in error)
                    {
                        //Log the error as needed.
                    }
                }
                pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipe.Commands.Add(_command);
                var results2 = pipe.Invoke();
                var error2 = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                if (error2.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (PSObject er in error2)
                    {
                        //log the error as needed.
                    }
                }
                return results2;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log the exception as needed.
        }
    }
```

This lets you log errors better, and log exceptions better. it also lets you return a PS object if you need to use the created item / output.

To use a function:

```
    public void addAzureGroupMember(object _group, object _user)
    {
        Command command = new Command("Add-AzureADGroupMember");
        command.Parameters.Add("ObjectId", _group);
        command.Parameters.Add("RefObjectId", _user);
        Collection<PSObject> results = runAzureCommands(command, "addAxureGroupMember");
    }
```

Once you build the main function, it lets you create extra functions quickly. Also, when / if it breaks, you only have to change one main function, instead of fixing every single powershell script you created using the template.

We use this for connecting to powershell AD and templates like this for other powershell items including ExchangeOnline and MsolService.